C# XmlWriter skips high surrogate character
I'm using the XmlWriter class to generate a large xml file. Everything works as expected, except for one particular file I have to generate. I have this string that contains the  (\u1F4A5) emoji.
This emoji is correctly serialized in most of the file.
<Name>Example &#x1F4A5;</Name>

However, out of a sudden, I get one line like this:
<Name>Example &#xDCA5; (asdf)</Name> 

The Name string is not the same, but both contain the same emoji, and the second string is also correctly serialized in other parts of the file.
I understand .NET store strings using UTF-16. In this encoding, this emoji corresponds to 0xD83D 0xDCA5. While debugging this issue, I inspected the memory region where the variable was stored, and I could see all bytes were there.
So it's almost like XmlWriter is skipping the high surrogate character. I couldn't reproduce this issue in a smaller test. It only happens with this large file when the application is running inside our Kubernetes cluster. If I run the same code locally, I get the correct serialization every time.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
        "Windows-1252",
        new EncoderReplacementFallback(),
        new DecoderReplacementFallback()
    ),
    Indent = true,
});

//...

foreach(var item in items){
    //...
    writer.WriteElementString("Name", item.Name);
    //...
}

I was initially running .NET 6, and upgrading to .NET 8 didn't help. The application runs inside a Docker container with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 as the base image, so, apart from the kernel, the environment should be the same everywhere.
What could explain this behavior?

Use UTF-8 Encoding: Consider switching to UTF-8 encoding, which can handle all Unicode characters, including emojis. Modify your XmlWriterSettings as follows:
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true,
});

Explicitly Handle Surrogates: If you must stick with a specific encoding (like Windows-1252), you can explicitly handle surrogate pairs before writing them to the XML. Ensure that the string does not have any unpaired surrogates.
Sanitize Input: If certain strings are problematic, you might want to sanitize or validate them before writing, ensuring that all emojis are properly encoded.
Check for High Surrogates: Before calling WriteElementString, you can inspect the item.Name string to see if it contains unpaired high surrogates and handle them accordingly.
